# docker run command change to .yaml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes

below is my start container docker run command:

```
docker run -it -d --name=aaa--net=host -v /opt/headedness/phantomjs:/data/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs -v /opt/ctcrawler/log:/data/log XXX/app/aaa:latest -id aaa -endpoint http://localhost:8080/c2/ -selenium http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

How to change it to a yaml file? I have try many ways,but still can`t working...
below is my .yaml file(pls help...)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: aaa
spec:
  containers:
    - name: aaa
      image: xxx/app/aaa:latest
      net: "host"
      args:
      - -id: aaa
      - -phantomjs: /data/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
      - -capturedPath: /data/log
      - -endpoint: http://wwww/c2/
      - -selenium: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
      - -proxy: n/a
      imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey
```

Comment: Yes, syntax doesn't look OK. For example `-v` -> `volumes`, .... I'll recommend to read some example first - https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/f5082b6dd7a06db0d1c2a043c202bdd21331e342/docs/user-guide/configmap/volume-pod.yaml

Comment: Yes,I have try.But can`t working.

Comment: how to configure -endpoint: http://wwww/c2/ to yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Your Spec is invalid. 
For host network set `spec.securityContext.HostNetwork: true` 
Use hostPath volumes to mount directories on the host. 
If it is configuration data, you can use a gitRepo volume or ConfigMap starting from v1.2.

Comment: like this
right ?
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: aaa
spec:
  containers:
    - name: aaa
      image: xxx/app/aaa:latest
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /opt/headedness/phantomjs
        name: phantomjs
      - mountPath: /opt/ctcrawler/log
        name: capturedpath
  volumes:
    - name: phantomjs
      path: /data/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
    - name: capturedpath
      path: /data/log
  securityContext:
      HostNetwork: true
      imagePullPolicy: Always
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: myregistrykey